# for /f nested inside for /f command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How do I successfully run this command without too many lines. The file I am referencing `mysessions.txt` contains list of computers in which I had RDP sessions but I don't want to log in to them before I log off. I wan to run `logoff` command against the session ID in the `qwinsta user /server:A%` so that it is only that user session that is logged off. When I ran the `qwinsta` command on its own the third item in the output is the session id that is why I declared the token in the main command as `3` and it is the variable `%a`.

The command I ran is below:

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims= " %a in ('for /f  %A in (mysessions.txt) do qwinsta user /server:%A') do echo %a
```

The error message I get is below:

```
The system cannot find the file 'for /f %A in (mysessions.txt.
```

Comment: What have you done to try and understand the error message? The message clearly explains that the text between the single primes is being interpreted as a file name. What have you done to rewrite the one-liner to something that works?

Comment: @AdrianHHH bo be precise: a part of the text is interpreted as filename. Don't be _too_ harsh. rmon's syntax looks correct, if you are not used to escape some characters in some special circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stephan has identified the problem, and offered a perfectly working solution. There is another syntax that works equally as well.

The command executed by FOR /F is executed within a child process via the /C argument to CMD. Looking at the CMD help, you can see that CMD will strip enclosing quotes around the /C argument before it executes the command.

So you can use the following:

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims= " %a in ('"for /f %A in (mysessions.txt) do qwinsta user /server:%A"') do echo %a
```

This works great because there are no additional double quotes. But if the command already has its own quotes, then you are back in a position of possibly having to escape some characters.

---

But couldn't you use two loops in a more conventional manner like this?

```
for /f %S in (mysessions.txt) do for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %A in ('qwinsta user /server:%S') do echo %A
```

You might prefer the following cleaner output that hides the commands and simply lists the session, followed by the result.

```
for /f %S in (mysessions.txt) do @for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %A in ('qwinsta user /server:%S') do @echo %S: %A
```

Comment: thanks @dbenham the first suggested script worked. that's great. I will with other scripts you suggested later.

Comment: hi @dbenham, i used the suggested two loops and it worked a treat. my colleague used similar method long ago but he was using tokens=2 instead of tokens=3. below shows what i was actually trying to achieve:

Comment: for /f %A in (mysessions.txt) do for /F "tokens=3 delims= " %a in ('qwinsta user /serv
er:%A^') do echo %a &&  echo %A

Comment: for /f %A in (mysessions.txt) do for /F "tokens=3 delims= " %a in ('qwinsta user /server:%A^') do logoff %a /server:%A

Answer (score 2):

ugly escaping needed...  Try this:

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims= " %a in ('for /f %A in (mysessions.txt^) do qwinsta user /server:%A') do echo %a
```

the paranthese after `mysessions.txt` closes the outer `for` unintended (too early) - therefore the syntax error. By escaping it with a caret, you tell the outer `for` to ignore it.

Comment: that worked. that's great thanks. it displayed the session ID, so now i can replace  "do echo %a" with "do logoff %a /server:%A" to logoff all my logon session from the computers in the file mysessions.txt.